# Controlling width of datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I have a `table(id="example")`. I am applying datatable theme to it.

```
var oTable=$(#"example").datatable();
```

I want the width of the datatable to be 80% of the page. To solve this I have redefined the class like this on my View:

```
<style>

/*Overriding  datable class to cater this page's need*/
    .dataTables_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
        *zoom: 1;
        width: 80%;
    }
</style>
```

Here I have redefined the width of datatable on the view.

This works for me at this point of time though.Please let me know if  I am missing any predefined attribute of jquery datatable for width control.

Ur help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#example").dataTable({
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bJQueryUI": true,
"bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation 
"aoColumns": [
  { "sWidth": "30%" }, // 1st column width 
  { "sWidth": "30%" }, // 2nd column width 
  { "sWidth": "40%" } // 3rd column width and so on 
]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `table` automatically takes `width` from `plugin`, try this **CSS**,

```
#example{
   width:100% !important;/* now it will take width according to your outer div */
}
```

Also it may be typo, use `$("#example")` instead `$(#"example")`

And use **[bAutoWidth](https://datatables.net/usage/features)**

**Script**

```
$(function(){
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan.It worked for me in a sample, but while in my application,only ""bAutoWidth": false" didn't look sufficient,so I defined each column width altogether.